# Javascript tabs initial content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am seeking advice on how to show content and then hide it depending on which tab is clicked. So I would like a div showing on page load and then you can switch between them. Currently my script only shows them and hides after you click on a link to show.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/4310/)

```
$('.targetDiv').hide();
$('.show').click(function () {
    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
});

$('.hide').click(function () {
    $('.targetDiv').hide();

});
```

Comment: seriously i couldn't able to understand the question even though i read the question twice.

Comment: You seem to be already showing and hiding the content when a particular div link is clicked.

Comment: For what I understood, your demo is working fine

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy So when the page loads I want something already in the div, then once a links clicked it changes it to the that content. At the moment when the page loads it shows no content.

Comment: @Pierre the demo works fine yes, but I need say the first div to already be loaded before I click on anything so there is at least something on the page without having to click to load it.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/4313/

Comment: I like @MelanciaUK answer, generic

Comment: @Pierre I think it's better not to rely on the `div` ID _$("#div1").show()_, as per the OP HTML markup they're already using a `target` attribute to find out which `div` to manipulate. On top of that you save a call. Why hide all and then show the first if you can just ignore the first one when hiding all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your code

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#div1').show();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hide all the panels at the start, but ignore the first one:

```
// When page is loaded.
$(function () {
    // Hide all panels except the first one.
    $('.targetDiv').not(':first').hide();

    $('.show').click(function () {
        // You can just trigger the click to the Hide All.
        $('.hide').click();

        $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
    });

    $('.hide').click(function () {
        $('.targetDiv').hide();
    });
});
```

This way you can save one call - to hide all and then show the first.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/4314/)

[jQuery .not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

[jQuery .first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

Answer (score 1):

Really hard to say what you want and why, but on load you simply can do this:

```
$('.targetDiv').hide();
$('#div1').show(); //if you know the id
//OR
$('.targetDiv:first').show(); // alway the first for example...
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would be to hide only the divs you need to hide at the start, like so:

```
$('.targetDiv').hide();
```

to

```
$('.targetDiv:not(#div1)').hide();
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/4wnyL/